# Redirect traffic from VPN server to VPN client

Tags: raspberry-pi, openvpn, wireguard

I had a setup with a RaspberryPi at home with PiHole and a Wireguard VPN server, so that with my phone I was always routing my traffic through my home server and filtering my mobile traffic. Now I'd like to put a VPN in output to that (NordVPN, to be specific), but since I start the NordVPN connection my phone can't neither access the internal network (through a ssh client) nor the internet.

This is my routing table with both VPN up (wg0 is the wireguard interface between my phone and the raspberry, and tun0 is the outgoing VPN from the raspberry to NordVPN - the *** ip is the specific server i'm connecting to):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.6.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
***.***.***.*** 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

How can I make my phone reach both the internal network via SSH and the internet via the NordVPN tunnel?

I hope I made myself clear,
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The first problem was that handshake responses were routed to the tun0 interface due to the default route set up by the OpenVPN client.

To solve this problem:

```
#adds the default route to respond via the eth0
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table 1
#adds the default route to the local network
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 table 1
#adds the response route
ip route add 10.6.0.0/24 dev wg0 table 1
#adds the policy so that all the traffic that comes through eth0 goes back by eth0
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 table 1
```

So now everything that comes in `eth0` will be intercepted by that rule and routed using what's inside table 1, namely those 3 rules that route all the traffic back to the same interface.

Now we can successfully complete the handshake and get to the local network, but we still can't get to the internet, and that's our second problem. The wireguard client by default (or at least my configuration which was installed with piVPN) puts up an iptables nat rule to NAT the traffic from the wireguard subnet to the `eth0` interface. But with the new routing table, that traffic gets directly to the `tun0` interface, so it won't be natted and would go out with its original ip (`10.6.0.2` or something). So we have to add another iptables nat rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -s 10.6.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Hope this can help somebody else, it took me an entire weekend to figure out -- I had to start from scratch!